# setTimeout pass array by value (in coffee)

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I'm sorry to post a question that must be so common, but I struggle to properly pass an array by value to a setTimeout function:

```
for exi in [1..5]
  # I just re-create an array at each iteration
  mdopkt = [ 
    exi + 5,
  ]


  delay = (ms, func) -> setTimeout func, ms

  sendpkt = (st) ->
    arg = EJSON.stringify st 
    root.zmqPush.send arg

  md = mdopkt.slice(0)
  foo = -> sendpkt md
  delay 1000, foo
```

The above code just does not work, as the "mdopkt" array is changed before the end of the delay. The zmqPush is just executed 5 times with an mdopkt containing the same 5+5 value.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to execute async code inside synchronous `for` loop, so by the time the first async call is actually happens your for loop is already finished executing. The other problem is that you're redefining your `exi,`mdopkt`and`md` variables on each iteration.

To fix this problem you should create a closure, and there are two common ways to do it in CoffeScript.

#### Using [`Array::forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for` loop

```
[1..5].forEach (exi) ->
  # your code
```

#### Using [`do` keyword](http://rzrsharp.net/2011/06/27/what-does-coffeescripts-do-do.html)

```
for exi in [1..5] then do (exi) ->
  # your code
```

Comment: I was not doing the closure at the right place. the "do" did it. Big thanks !